# Better way to execute nested for loops to generate a dict?

Tags: python

Is there a better way in python to generate a list dictionaries, containing values from lists, than using nested `for` loops?

Example:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ... ,'z']
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chars = ["!", "@", "#", "$"]

objects = []
for letter in alphabet:
    for number in numbers:
        for char in characters:
            objects.append({
                'letter': letter,
                'number': number,
                'char': char
            })

print objects
# [{letter: 'a', 'number': 0, 'char':'!'}, {letter: 'a', 'number': 0, 'char':'@'}, ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make a list of dicts that contains every combination of three lists.  Using nested `for` loops in the example above, this is 26 x 10 x 4 loops.  I looked at using `zip`, but only merges lists and doesn't give every unique combination.

Is there a pythonic way to get it done quicker than 26 x 10 x 4 loops?

Is there a way to accomplish this lazily via a generator?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce the generator you requested:

```
from itertools import product

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ... ,'z']
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chars = ["!", "@", "#", "$"]

combinations = product(alphabet, numbers, chars)
generator = ({'letter': l, 'number': n, 'char': c} for l, n, c in combinations)
```

As this is a generator, it will be evaluated only when needed:

```
list(generator)
```

Answer (score 3):

funnily enough it is itertools.product

```
import itertools
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','z']
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chars = ["!", "@", "#", "$"]
my_iter = itertools.product(alphabet,numbers,chars)
my_keys = "letter number char".split()
for data in my_iter:
    print dict(zip(my_keys,data))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to compute the Cartesian product between all provided iterables:

```
import itertools
import string

for letter, number, char in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, string.digits, string.punctuation):
    print({'letter': letter, 'number': number, 'char': char})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    generator = [a+b for a,b in product(list(range(1,n+1)),list(range(1,n+1)))]
    c = Counter(generator)
    h=0
    print(c)
    for k in c:
        print(k)
    print(h)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It would be helpful if you could add some details on how/why your answer works.